# Unable to invoke DialogFlow agent via explicit invocation

Tags: actions-on-google, dialogflow-es, google-assistant-sdk

I am unable to invoke a intent say, "ABCwelcomeintent" which has event trigger of "GOOGLE ASSISTANT WELCOME". This intent has been mapped to explicit invocation in Google integration settings and synced with actions list.

The training phrases include ABC and talk to ABC (both). I am able to invoke by just saying **talk to ABC** to Google Assistant.

Can we invoke the app by just saying,

> ABC

only and **not**

> talk to ABC

I want to invoke bot without trigger "talk to" and just only ABC. Such way is not mentioned according to the official [documentation](https://developers.google.com/actions/discovery/explicit). Please update the official documentation if there is a way.

The reason for this is my current live bot is unhealthy according to health check probe bot by Google which tries to invoke the bot by just querying "ABC". So I also need to do the same way. And this Health check probe bot will take down my live bot from Production to obsolete.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 2):

You may use [implicit invocation](https://developers.google.com/actions/discovery/implicit) to make Google Assistant suggest user to use your Assistant App. Otherwise, for explicit invocation, you will need to say "Ok Google! Talk to", "Hey Google! Speak to", "Ok Google! ask" to start the conversation with your assistant app.

Comment: If we have to say "talk to" to invoke and start conversation, then what's the deal with the Health Probe bot of Google. Have you faced any such issue ?

Comment: There may be a case what you are writing does not sound like that word. If your invocation name "ABC" in the phrase "talk to ABC" does not sound like "ABC" then it may fail. So try to use a name that sounds and is written in same. If there are Silent characters then it may sound different from what it is written.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you have two different issues here.

**Health Check**

The health check is done through an automated process that sends a payload identical to what it would send if a user triggered it, with a flag indicating it is the health ping. No user actually says anything.

If the health check is failing, then it means that your service isn't responding in some fashion. Check your logs and Dialogflow's logs to indicate what might be happening - is your webhook responding? Are you sending back invalid data? Is Dialogflow misconfigured? There may be many reasons for this. In order to figure out which, we would need to see a lot more information to help you - details of the error Google is reporting from the health check, your Dialogflow logs, the results of your own testing in the simulator, etc.

**Name Triggering**

Triggering based on just the command "ABC" is a separate issue - there are many ways that your action could be invoked.

- All Actions will start with "Hey Google, talk to " or "Hey Google, ask ".
- If you have identified specific built-in Intents that your Action can handle, you may also have registered these.
- Additionally, Google will identify Implicit Triggers that it may suggest to users that might trigger your Action. You have little control over this, but this is somewhat like SEO - if your Action does this, then Google may suggest it.
- Finally, users can setup a Routine or Shortcut which triggers your Action when they say "Hey Google, something".